# Create AND add user to sharepoint site via code

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm curious about the best/most efficient way to do this.

I've already set up my sharepoint 2010 site, and it is configured to use FBA.  What i'd like to do is allow users to create their own accounts by filling out a form (the form will sit on a public sharepoint site, and filling it out creates a user in the membership database which is used for validation to enter the FBA sharepoint site).

I'm familiar with using the asp CreateWizard tool to build user accounts as part of a .Net web application, but I'm not sure on how to develop this as a webpart for use in a sharepoint site, as a webpart doesn't have the config file to store connection string and membership/role provider info.

Can this user creation form be put in a webpart and deployed to other sites, or is there another/better way to add this functionality to sharepoint (allowing users to register/create their own FBA accounts for access)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing not much difference between SharePoint and regular ASP.Net for this.

The membership provider will need to be configured in the SharePoint web.config, including connection strings. However, it does not actually need to be used for login, so you can still create users in that membership provide from a different site.

I use a slightly different approach though - set up an anonymously accessible page in your site (in layouts is probably easiest, though a page within a site may be better for branding) and put controls on that page to create (and log in) a new user. You will need to call EnsureUser and possibly CreateUserProfile to give the new user access to anything, but aside from that it's all standard .net.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know you could have public pages in an FBA site.  Can I do all this in sharepoint designer 2010?  I tried adding the <asp:createwizard> control to a new page but sharepoint designer threw an error saying that tag is not allowed in xhtml 1.0

Comment: Oh, and adding the connection string and membership provider info to the site web.config worked perfectly, thanks, but now i'm curious as to how it can be done with just an aspx page and user controls

Comment: With difficulty. There's nothing to stop you connecting to a database with a hardcoded connection string or instantiating a particular membership provider, but you probably won't be able to use the out of box components.

Comment: Designer should work, though I haven't tried that - you may find that that error is actually just a warning - the tags available on the actual site are not necessarily the same as the ones vs/designer thinks are available.

Comment: I moved on to building the pages through visual studio 2010 rather than using sharepoint designer, and I had another follow-up that maybe you could advise me on (if not, don't worry, you've been more than helpful already).

As I've said, it's an FBA site and I followed this example to create the pages (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/06/28/creating-a-sharepoint-site-page-with-code-behind-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, that last comment came out weird. Anyway, I tried building a site page and ran into a different issue which I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034891/create-user-wizard-causes-error-on-sharepoint-site