# create user wizard causes error on sharepoint site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I've built a new sharepoint site page using the example I found here:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/creating-a-sharepoint-site-page-with-code-behind-using-visual-studio-2010)

The purpose of the page is to add a new user to the aspnet membership database that serves as the authentication provider for my sharepoint site, which uses forms based authentication.

I've slightly customized the asp createuser control.

The sharepoint site is forms based but the top level site is accessible anonymously, and I've created a subsite for members (hence the user registration page).  The site page is in the top level site so that people can register.

If I'm already logged in and fill out the form, the user is successfully added to the membership store, however if I access the page anonymously and fill out the form, the user is successfully added to the membership database, but I can no longer navigate the website, I keep getting http 500 page cannot be displayed errors until I clear the browser  cache and cookies.

I don't think it's a programming error but more likely something to do with site security and authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user is created successfully and page is redirected to the one you provided in **ContinueDestinationPageUrl** property, the page is being loaded with the recently created user’s credentials. Since you haven’t added this new user to your MOSS site, you’ll get Access Denied error. So, in order to resolve this issue, you need to set **LoginCreatedUser** property of the control to **false**, so that page is loaded with the original user’s credentials, not with the one’s recently created.